# How to build a Vector of strings (Containing Spaces)?

Tags: c++, string, getline

I was trying to build a vector of strings.
Some of the strings also contain Spaces.
That's why I was using getline(cin,string_name).
My code looks like

```
      for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
        {
            getline(cin, s);
            vec.push_back(s);

        }
```

When I was taking input

```
ADAM BOB JOHNSON
```

It stopped after taking two input words, and the vector contents displayed are

```
(HERE SPACE IS DISPLAYED)ADAM BOB
```

What does it mean.Is it taking NULL string as input for the first string ? 
It will be really helpful if someone tells me how to take the strings and display it.Thanks.

Comment: which language is this? and `some kind of error` ? what is this error?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], it's impossible to reproduce your problem with just this code snippet

Comment: Sorry it was not any error,but was not giving expected output @Yazan

Comment: Can you please tell me what is missing ? I have tried to explain the issue properly @UnholySheep

Comment: I was basically solving this problem https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/11274486/dashboard#s=p0.Can anyone tell me how to take input in the second case.

Comment: Please read the article I linked. We cannot take your code snippet and compile it to get the same problem you are having (and if someone expands it themselves they get the correct result, as demonstrated by the "answer" from Binpord)

Comment: Here is the issue sir : https://ideone.com/Ak5jDE @UnholySheep

Answer (score 1):

Abhijit,
Your information is, obviously, not enough. Assuming that your code is written on C++, I made this test cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> vec;
    std::string s;
    int n = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        getline(std::cin, s);
        vec.push_back(s);

        std::cout << vec.at(i) << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with g++ and fed it with "ADAM BOB JOHNSON" string on input. Everything worked as it planned and it output was exact same as input. So I can see no error in here.

Sorry, cannot make it a comment due to insufficient reputation so far.

---

UPD: Found the issue. getline first gets '\n', we left after '3' (which is needed for std::cin >> n;) hence, you just need to ignore one string. The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;


    std::vector<std::string> vec;
    std::string s;
    std::getline(std::cin, s);

    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        std::getline(std::cin, s);
        vec.push_back(s);

        // std::cout << vec.at(i) << std::endl;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;++i){

        std::cout << vec[i] <<" " << std::endl;
    }




    return 0;

}
```

works fine for me.

And yep, @pmaxim98 made it first, sorry, was editing the reply and haven't seen your comment.

Comment: Yes It is printing properly inside the loop,but when iterated over the vecor again after pushing the stirngs it doesnot show the third stirng and shows space at first postion.

Comment: Can anyone help me here please?

Comment: @Abhijit Sarkar try using `std::cin.ignore()` right after `cin >> n`. See [here](https://ideone.com/zLfct7).

Comment: Thank You So MUCH.This is what I was looking for.@pmaxim98